# Font with (fairly) symmetrical S (or how to edit Arial's S)

Tags: font-recommendation

I'm looking for a sans serif font (similar to Arial) with a (fairly) symmetrical 'S'

This is Arial's S:

[image]

See how the top part is so different from the bottom?

Even if not 100% symmetrical, if somebody can help me find a better one?

**Or know how to edit this one (Arial) to at least improve it...** I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The 'S' is a weird glyph...there's a reason why it's usually not exactly symmetrical.

Helvetica is more symmetrical than Arial:

[image: Helvetica 'S']

Another font that came to mind is [Giogio Sans](https://commercialtype.com/typefaces/giorgio/sans) - different than Arial, to be sure, but certainly pretty symmetrical:

[image: Giorgio Sans 'S']

[League Gothic](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/League-Gothic) is different than Arial but has a fair amount of symmetry to it (depending on how you define symmetry, I guess):

[image: League Gothic 'S']

One more symmetrical font that's not like Arial - [Tungsten](http://www.typography.com/fonts/tungsten/overview/):

[image: Tungsten 'S']

Comment: You mention there's a reason why the S is not symmetrical--can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @Eric I dunno, it's just a visual thing, what we're used to culturally. Try doodling 'S' letters on paper without thinking, and see how they're formed. Do you find that the letters are heavier/larger on the bottom part of the S? Try drawing top-heavy ones...they don't look right.

Comment: Alright, that's fair. I just thought you might have a study or something that showed that typographical purpose of drawing an S like that. (I know top-heavy Ss look weird, but I'm more curious about symmetrical ones.)

Comment: @Eric - heh, you exposed me :P no study or anything. I just remember working on my own font and trying to get cute with the letters, and I was never happy with my "S". It's a weird letter!

Comment: I agree getting s to work takes as much time as the rest of the fonts basic latin letters, not accounting keerns. Its usually the one that bothers me, made 6 fonts and 5 of those i had to redo the s many times.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have access/ability to use Adobe Illustrator? If so, right click on the text and select "Create Outlines". Then you will have a path that you can modify.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you draw a new S in a font editor using a grid. Here is my attempt to create a symmetrical S. It does look a little bit unbalanced but it will always do if you are striving towards symmetry.

[image: Symmetrical S]

[Font file in Birdfont format](http://birdfont.org/misc/Symmetrical_S.bf)